# Yahoo IMAP Spam folder not recognized by Outlook 2007

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail, microsoft-outlook, imap

Yahoo uses the name `Bulk Mail` for it's spam folder, when connecting via IMAP.

However, Outlook 2007 by default uses the name `Junk E-mail`.

So whenever I connect to my Yahoo email account with Outlook, it makes this folder, which then appears on [ymail.com](http://ymail.com) in the web interface.

How can I make Outlook understand that it should use the Bulk Mail folder instead? (Thunderbird has a feature to customize the name of the spam folder, but I cannot find it on Outlook.)

Comment: When did Yahoo start allowing IMAP?

Comment: Do you have a premium account, or free?

Comment: @ekaj - It's a free account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read and discovered, this isn't possible. My suggestion is to change the Yahoo! Spam folder to Junk E-Mail (I believe this is possible), which will avoid extra folders being created.

I am surprised Microsoft hasn't added a way by now to disable the Junk Email folder..

Comment: Sadly, I think you may be right.